# Can I check the number of buttons in a screen in appium

Tags: java, android, appium

I'm landing in a screen which has 10 or more buttons. I just want to check how many buttons are present in the screen when opened for the first time.

Comment: @KristapsMežavilks I tried to get the number of buttons on a specific screen, here I want to check the buttons clicking state. So first I'll check the count of buttons, from the count I want to check each button clicking state by using for loop

Answer (score 0):

I have never personally tried this but there is a `findElements(By)` function which gives you back a list of elements. So I would assume you could just get the number of buttons by getting the size of the returned list.

That is `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//<Button Type depending on OS>").size();`

For example for xcode 8:

```
int numButtons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//XCUITestButton")).size();
```

Note I am writing this response away from

Answer (score 0):

In Android, if you do WebElements it will show you only those elements that are present on the visible screen. In your case if all the buttons are present on the visible screen then you can just call WebElements to find the count of buttons.

```
List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.className(android.widget.Button));
System.out.println(list.size());
```

Otherwise you would have to scroll down on the screen and then keep on adding to your list to get the complete list of buttons.